# Asus N56V - Instant key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xubuntu, asus

is there a way to make the Instant key of an asus N56V work under Ubuntu/Xubuntu?

I'm using Xubuntu 13.04. I'm trying to set a function for this Instant key thru Setting Manager->Keyboard, but I'm not able (the key is not recognized).
However, this is what I get using `xev` and pressing the Instant key:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
root 0x9f, subw 0x0, time 3698815, (169,-16), root:(763,301),
state 0x0, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
root 0x9f, subw 0x0, time 3698815, (169,-16), root:(763,301),
state 0x0, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have similar laptop and I found the solution here: http://dev-loki.blogspot.com/2006/04/mapping-unsupported-keys-with-xmodmap.html

Basically you have the keycode and the next step is to map this code to a key symbol (keysym). To load automatically the binding at startup you have to create .Xmodmap file in your home directory. This file is being red by xmodmap when the X-Server is started.
Add the following line in .Xmodmap:

```
keycode 248 = F13
```

and save the file. To load the mapping manually for the first time run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` in terminal. Now you can use the key to make a keyboard shortcut in Xfce.